# How do I use an EXE in the Chocolatey package from chocolateyInstall.ps1?

Tags: package, installation, chocolatey

I am building a self-contained Chocolatey package. The package folder contains: `app.nuspec`, `app.exe`, `app.nupkg`, and the `tools` subfolder. The `chocolateyInstall.ps1` is like this:

```
$packageName = 'app'
$fileType = 'exe'
$silentArgs = '/VERYSILENT'
$url = '../app.exe' # the location of the file relative to the tools folder

Install-ChocolateyPackage $packageName $fileType $silentArgs $url
```

When I run:

```
choco install app -y
```

I get:

```
Copy-Item : cannot find the path C:\ProgramData\app.exe because does not exist
```

How can I make this work? I've read a bit about 'create self-contained package with shims' but I don't really get how to use that? Any help? thank you

EDIT 1

I have found also this other solution here (http://patrickhuber.github.io/2015/03/19/creating-enterprise-versions-of-public-chocolatey-packages.html) that does work. So in my case that would be:

```
$directory = $PSScriptRoot
$packageName = 'app'
$fileType = 'exe'
$silentArgs = '/VERYSILENT'
$url = Join-Path $directory '..\app.exe'     


Install-ChocolateyPackage $packageName $fileType $silentArgs $url
```

I was wondering what is the `$PSScriptRoot` variable?

Comment: It doesn't work with relative paths. Take a look at Gary's answer below. Also keep in mind that `choco new pkgname` generates all that you need for getting this right.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` is the same as `$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)` but an automatic variable that is available in PowerShell v3+. We recommend you use the older method - if only only have machines that are 3+ (aka Windows 8/Windows 2012 and up or have upgrade WMF on all of your other machines), then you are fine to use `$PSScriptRoot` without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing a Chocolatey Package that contains the exe/msi, you can use the `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` helper method, rather than the `Install-ChocolateyPackage` helper method.  This is documented on the Chocolatey Wiki [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyInstallPackage)

This works in very much the same way as the other helper method, with the exception that it doesn't want/need to download the exe/msi.  It uses the path that it is provided, and installs from there.

You can find a complete example of what is required in the [ChocolateyGUI package](https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/blob/develop/ChocolateyPackage/chocolateyInstall.ps1), which does a very similar thing.

The crux of it is shown below for reference:

```
$packageName = 'ChocolateyGUI'
$fileType = 'msi'
$silentArgs = '/quiet'
$scriptPath =  $(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$fileFullPath = Join-Path $scriptPath 'ChocolateyGUI.msi'

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage $packageName $fileType $silentArgs $fileFullPath
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow we're still missing the explanation of script- and caller-relative paths. In this case, Chocolatey is executing from

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\Chocolatey\choco.exe
```

Your script is telling it to go up one level and look for `app.exe`, that's

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\app.exe
```

What Gary's answer implies, by using `$MyInvocation` is that you need to construct this path relative to the script's location, not the caller's location. You found another method of doing that by joining the path with `$PSScriptRoot`.

Both of these variables are known as ["Automatic variables"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

> $MyInvocation
>
> Contains an information about the current command, such as the name, 
>   parameters, parameter values, and information about how the command was
>   started, called, or "invoked," such as the name of the script that called
>   the current command.
>
> $MyInvocation is populated only for scripts, function, and script blocks. 
>   You can use the information in the System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
>   object that $MyInvocation returns in the current script, such as the path
>   and file name of the script ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) or the name of a
>   function ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) to identify the current command. 
>   This is particularly useful for finding the name of the current script.

And

> $PSScriptRoot
>
> Contains the directory from which a script is being run.
>
> In Windows PowerShell 2.0, this variable is valid only in script modules
>   (.psm1). Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, it is valid in all scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation..It make more sense to me now